# Please provide an example of the .format() function where the index field is left blank

Tags: python-3.x

Alright I am a bit confused. what I'm learning to program from says that the index fields for the .format() method can be left blank and if this is the case that the parameters are just filled in to the slots in a left to right fashion. I have tried to find answers to this question but haven't found any and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could clear this up for me with some easily understandable examples and explanations of how you would use the .format() method without index values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
print("The value of {} is {}".format("foo", 5))
```

This is equivalent to

```
print("The value of {0} is {1}".format("foo", 5))
```

Comment: Thank you this helps but is it possible to leave the index fields blank while at the same time adding other formatting options such as width and precision if so please show

Comment: Yes, you can add formatting options without using the index value.